# Is it wrong if I don't omit 'the' when there are multiple 'the' items?

Tags: grammaticality, articles, conjunctions, definite-articles, conjunction-reduction

Someone claims that the following is ungrammatical:

> We focus on the parameters of the representative frequency, the composition of sounds and the sequence complexity.

They claim it should instead be,

> We focus on the parameters of the representative frequency, sound composition, and sequence complexity.

Another example:

> - No effects were observed on the cell growth, the cell proliferation, the cell cycle distribution, and the gene expression. [allegedly incorrect]
> - No effects were observed on the cell growth, cell proliferation, cell cycle distribution, and gene expression. [allegedly the only correct version]

Is this true? I doubt the validity of their claim. Indeed, I think both versions are equally grammatical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either is grammatical.

So it becomes a question of how much emphasis you want to give to each individual item.

If you are making the point that all items are affected and want to get that across to the listener, then repetition of the article can be helpful.

Comment: @Rathony [Quite right](https://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/eitherare.html) I have edited. Thanks.